# How to apply .on('load'), .scroll(), and .resize() to a sticky scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a functionality that sets the top position of a div (`#sticky`) on load and on scroll. But of course the variables will change as the size of the page changes, so I have need for the `.resize()` event.

When I run the code on page load and on scroll, it works fine but if I resize the page, then scroll the top position of `#sticky` gets set to 0.

How do I correct this problem?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  sticky = $('#sticky'),
  stickyPadding = 80;

  if($(sticky).length && ($(window).width() >= 900)){
    $(sticky).css('position','relative');

    $(window).on('load',function(){
      getStickyMeasurements();
      stickEl()();
      $(window).resize(function(){
        getStickyMeasurements();
      });
      $(window).scroll(stickEl());
    });
  }
});
function getStickyMeasurements(){
  elHeight = $(sticky).outerHeight();
  initialElToTop = $(sticky).offset().top;
  dynamicStickyLimiter = $('.entry-content-extra').length ? $('.entry-content-extra').offset().top : $('footer').offset().top
  stickyLimit = dynamicStickyLimiter - initialElToTop;
}

function stickEl(){
  return function(){
    elTopModifier = $(window).scrollTop() - initialElToTop;

    if( stickyLimit <= (elTopModifier + elHeight + stickyPadding)){
      stickyTopResult = stickyLimit - elHeight;
    }else if($(window).scrollTop() + stickyPadding >= initialElToTop){
      stickyTopResult = elTopModifier + stickyPadding;
    }else{
      stickyTopResult = 0;
    }
    $(sticky).css('top', stickyTopResult + 'px');
  }
}
```

Also, I know the scope of my variables needs work, so if you include that in part of your answer, that would be helpful as well (but not required of an accepted answer).

Comment: Why can't you just set the position to fixed?

Comment: Instead of wrapping resize event in load event (which doesn't really make sense), try using `$(window).on('load',function(){getStickyMeasurements();
      stickEl()();});` and don't wrap scroll binding inside it

Comment: @RichLinnell That would remove it from the flow of the document which would not achieve what I need it to.

Comment: @A.Wolff I modified it to be `$(window).on('load',function(){getStickyMeasurements();stickEl()();});
    $(window).resize(function(){getStickyMeasurements();});
    $(window).scroll(stickEl());` But the problem persists. Could event configuration not be the actual problem?